# The dark theme doesn't work for me in Visual studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

When switching to a dark theme, the display turns dark, and the code window remains white. Moreover, I decided to download Visual studio 2022 to another computer and everything worked there until I logged into my microsoft account, after that everything became the same.[This is what my IDE gives out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5Kp1.png)

Tried to reinstall Visual Studio 2022 :) Logged out of microsoft account.

Comment: Maybe try switching the theme to "system setting" option and see what it does (assuming your System is in a dark mode)